# An abbreviations list for AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

The wonderful AutoHotKey allows you to auto-expand abbreviations as you type them.

So you could have an `.ahk` script with many abbreviations like this:

```
::btw::by the way
::iirc::if I remember correctly
```

The problem is, I don't feel like writing out explicitly all the abbreviations I use in this file!

Is there anywhere a ready-made file with common abbreviations?

Answer (score 13):

Auto-expand abbreviations are very personal. It depends on your vocabulary. In my case, the list has grown over time, as I add words as required.

You can quickly edit with e.g. these two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations.

```
^!#e::  ; Edit the script by Alt+Ctrl++Win+E

;run, C:\Program Files\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe "%A_ScriptDir%\AutoHotkey-Robert-Dell.ahk"

Edit

return

^!#r:: ; Reload the script by Alt+Ctrl++Win+R

TrayTip, Restarted, Restart,1

Reload ; Reload AHK File

Return
```

My trimmed list (most of it was in Dutch) looks like this.
I often use a slash (/) to end, as this makes it easier to use abbreviation combinations that may also be part of a word.
By using the slash, I can easily  e.g. add an "s" after the word.

```
:?*:&&::&"  "&

:?*:&^&::&"  `; "&

:?*:&*&::&", "&

:?*:&@&::&"@"&

:?*:&$&::&"€"&

:?*:''::"{Space}  ; Turn two single quotes into a single double quote on a Dutch Keyboard setting

:?*:1l/::" One-Liner"{space}

:*:=vl::=vlookup(

:*:ahk/::AutoHotKey

:*:ad/::Active Directory

:?*:adm/::administration

:*:am/::Account Management

:*:actm/::Active Monitoring

:?*:appl/::application

:*:bf/::Break/Fix

:*:bl/::Business Line

:*:btw/::by the way

:*:bu/::Buiness Unit

:*:cc/::Competence Center

:*:cert/::certification

:*:col/::colleagues

:*:config/::configuration

:*:cons/::consultant

:*:cp/::c-Projects

:*:ce/::Coördination Engineer

:*:co/::Coordinator

:*:e/::E.Nr

:*:emp/::employee

:*:eng/::engineer

:*:fe/::Field Engineer

:*:feg/::Field Engineering

:*:gk/::Global Knowledge

:*:hr/::Human Resources

:*:hw/::Hardware

:*:ie/::Incident Engineer

:*:inc/::incident

:*:inf/::information

:*:inst/::installation

:*:ka/::knowledge article

:*:kb/::Knowledge Base

:*:km/::Knowledge Management

:*:ko/::knowledge object

:*:l/::level

:*:lab/::laboratory

:*:ld/::Learning & Development

:*:maint/::maintenance

:?*:mgr/::manager

:?*:mgt/::management

:?*:mkt/::marketing

:*:MOC/::Microsoft Office Communicator

:*:mssp/::MS SharePoint

:*:ms/::Microsoft

:?*:ops/::operations

:?*:org/::organisation

:?*:prof/::profile

:?*:prod/::product

:?*:proj/::project

:?*:pos/::position

:*:ps/::Partnership

:*:pwd/::password

:*:q/::Qualification

:*:qd/::Quick & Dirty

:*:qn/::question

:*:qe/::Qualification Engineer

:*:sa/::support agent

:*:sc/::Sales Consulting

:*:scy/:: Sales Consultancy

:*:std/::standaard

:?*:svc/::service

:*:sme/::subject matter expert

:*:sm/::Sales & Marketing

:*:sw/::Software

:*:te/::Technical Engineer

:*:tc/::Technical Consultant

:*:tcy/::Technical Consultancy

:?*:trng/::training

:*:tpm/::Third Party Maintenance

:*:var/::Value Added Reseller

:*:vc/::VoIP Connect

; MAANDEN

:*:jan/::januari

:*:feb/::februari

:*:mrt/::maart

:*:apr/::april

:*:aug/::augustus

:*:sep/::september

:*:okt/::oktober

:*:nov/::november

:*:dec/::december

:*:$$::€  ; Two $$ will turn into a €
```

Comment: I still think there is room for a much bigger, generalized list of abbreviations, and I'll be happy to see one.

Comment: Question: why are there *s and ?*s inbetween the colons? Wont it work the same if nothing is there?

Comment: Look halfway through this page for the role of these special characters: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there should be, but have not seen one. I have solved that issue myself by having a "medical transcriptions" folder added (if you search for this you could build on that with some parsing)

I have several similar list, for different languages (programming languages (including many shortkeys), Swedish, English), and due to the enormity use Breevy to organize them (as it is easier for >1000 abbreviations). It has a list of what you are looking for that comes with it, and if you look online you can find other lists (that you would have to modify to fit into the AutoHotkey script language).